# Make my script not to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I change my script in order not to refresh the page when I use the show_reply() and hide_reply() functions that I created?
Here is my script:

```
function show_reply($id){
    document.getElementById($id).style.display = "initial";
}
function hide_reply($id){
    document.getElementById($id).style.display = "none";
}
```

Forgot to metion that i`m calling these fuction like this

```
<a href="#" title="Reply" onclick="show_reply('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')"> Reply</a>
```

Comment: How are you calling these functions? On click in an `a` tag? Probably need to `preventDefault()`, but I'd need more details.

Comment: As @brbcoding mentioned, there is nothing in that particular code that is causing your page to refresh

Comment: See [this specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-cancelation) to see what you need to do. It's a `event.preventDefault()` to prevent the default behaviour of the `a`-tag -- I don't understand how this question is unclear. He's stating that the page refreshes when clicking on the link, which it clearly shouldn't (the reason of which is, that it's a link, therefore you need to make some adjustments).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working fiddle : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ps43C/)

You should prevent the action to goto other page.
//HTML

```
<a href="#" title="Reply" class="Classhref" onclick="show_reply('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>')"> Reply</a>
```

//Script

```
 $('.Classhref').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();

  }
```

Comment: THANKS!!!!!!! and sory for the dumb question.. i`m getting into javascript and this kind of stuff